# How to count letters in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to use a counter to count how many letters are in my string but I can't! I have tried numerous times.
Can someone tell me a way to do this?

Example: 
"Ebeneezer Scrooge is a very nasty man"

Sorry for the example, you can say anything... I just want to know how you do it

My code so far:

```
Name = "Wayne Rooney is overpaid"
NumberOfLetters = 0
for Letters in Name:
Name.count(Letters + 1)
print(NoOfLetters)
```

Comment: Well let's see what you've tried, and we can help fix it. We won't write code from scratch for you.

Comment: `print (len(example))`

Comment: A proper example would provide not only the input data, but also the expected output.  Just saying'...

Comment: `print sum(a in target_string.lower() for a in string.ascii_lowercase)`

Answer (score 0):

First filter letters from possible punctuation symbols, spaces and numbers, and join them into a new string `letters` as follows,

```
import re
letters = ''.join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", Name))
```

Then for counting the total number of letter occurrences,

```
len(letters)
```

and for counting the number of different letters occurring in `letters`, consider for instance,

```
len( set(letters) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import string
>>> print string.printable[10:62]
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>>> a
'this is a string with some letters 1010'
>>> letters = 0
>>> for i in a:
...     if i in string.printable[10:62]:
...             letters += 1
... 
>>> print letters
28
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from collections import Counter

name = "Wayne Rooney is overpaid"

print (sum(Counter("".join(name.split())).values()))
```

`Counter` method is usefull for string process, it returns a dict. Check first;

```
print (Counter(name))
```

You will see a dict with `keys=letters`,`values=counts of that letters`. Basically summing that values but using `split()` to delete spaces between letters.